# filter an Observable in switchMap operator

Tags: rxjs

I have a observable here from a wikipedia search

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/stackblitzes/typeahead/http/stackblitz.html

```
export class NgbdTypeaheadHttp {
  model: any;
  searching = false;
  searchFailed = false;
  myfilter = ['Mary' , 'Maryland'];

  constructor(private _service: WikipediaService) {}

  search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$.pipe(
      debounceTime(300),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      tap(() => this.searching = true),
      switchMap(term =>
        this._service.search(term).pipe(
          tap(() => this.searchFailed = false),
          catchError(() => {
            this.searchFailed = true;
            return of([]);
          }))
      ),
      tap(() => this.searching = false)
    )
}
```

After the Switchmap operator in the pipe i would like to filter out the response.

Items to be filtered are stored in the myFilter List.

I am stuck on how to do this.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, this should simply be a matter of using the RxJS `map` operator to filter out the array of results returned by that `WikipediaService` call. Here's a fork with the suggestion, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jtuutg?file=app/typeahead-http.ts (keep in mind this is case-sensitive if that matters to you)

Comment: Thanks miqh this is very similar to what i was looking for.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the problem. You `switchMap` will emit an array of results so you can use `map(results => results.filter(/* whatever */))`

Comment: You should add 'map' operator to transform result as you want it.

If you want to learn more about RxJS - take a look at my video-course https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/hands-rxjs-web-development-video